# How to override WP Query on product category page in woocommerce to display custom products from multiple categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

On a woocommerce category page, I want to show products from multiple categories. I have the list of product ids that are needed to be displayed. I am trying to override `WP_Query` using the below code:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ){

if ( !isset($_GET["querycheck"]) ) return;
        
if ( $query->is_main_query()  ) {
        
$post_ids = array(2043442,2043430); // Array of post IDs

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product', // Change 'post' to your custom post type if needed
    'post__in'       => $post_ids,
    'post_status'    => 'publish', // Limit to published posts
    'orderby'        => 'post__in', // Preserve the order of post IDs in the array
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Retrieve all posts
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

}
    
},9999999999,1);
```

However, no results are displayed on the category page. I tried using the `woocommerce products shortcode` but that doesn't have canonical URLs for different pages which might cause SEO issues. How to do this such that the list of pre-defined product ids is displayed along with pagination and product category filtering?

Comment: You need to copy archive-product.php template in your theme and modify it to your needs - https://woo.com/document/template-structure/